# Google app script API call fails: No access token in response

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to receive some data from my Google app script project, which is inside a Google sheet, to my local Python script. Later would be used with the Flask server.

I have already checked the official documentation, but I had no success. Then I tried Google Bard and Chat GPT as well to fix the code, but they both failed. I set the Google contest and I have generated the secret file as well, but currently, I don't use that. Also connected the GCP to the app script project. How should I call the function?

This is my current code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.exec']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "credentials.json"

# Load credentials using google-auth
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
    scopes=SCOPES
)

# Build the service
service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

function_name = 'apiTest'

def call_appscript_function(function_name):
    try:
        # Print token information before the refresh
        print("Token info before refresh:", credentials.token)
        
        request_body = {'functionName': function_name}
        response = service.scripts().run(scriptId='YOUR_SCRIPT_ID', body=request_body).execute()
        result = response['response']['results'][0]['result']
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# Call the function
result = call_appscript_function(function_name)
print(result)
```

Terminal message, that i got:

```
(venv) linux@LAPTOP-NM2KKLVJ:~/apiteszt$ /home/linux/apiteszt/venv/bin/python /home/linux/apiteszt/main.py
Token info before refresh: None
Error: ('No access token in response.', {'id_token': 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBlNzJkYTFkZjUwMWNhNmY3NTZiZjEwM2ZkN2M3MjAyOTQ3NzI1MDYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9hdXRoL3NjcmlwdC5leGVjIiwiYXpwIjoiYXBtc2JvdEBhcG1zYm90LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhcG1zYm90QGFwbXNib3QuaWFtLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiZXhwIjoxNzAxMDc5ODY1LCJpYXQiOjE3MDEwNzYyNjUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEwMjQzNTc5MTYxNDcwMDc5MDQ2MSJ9.PKLdc97zn-tJc-g11DqHqX5TlMt6MQemHAGVuB0jpc24GvRDTO82nMoXPOLAKJ7ACjc-TILAEZydcmPABxzwmfrwFjYnUxj1RBSUyui7VudjkF1YiG2zrmOP9TKHgt464TDOmwRd-2arxsFoCdYvDvDBzM0DHfGe8DxtIESac4xciCbOmgD3gC0f_tmSPKjLlslfbEO_ZtSTE9ACN-WJjduzbWaZ6f_WaI1nMKHR3Y3T1V0jCYPVnFFJ6fWmT75Qs1BT_2G_Rp0fd8JL7emP4rMVkU1owTecVJZapc8zSym14x-A6lsXv1mYEdy8Vgo8UQrX8Rj5BwEg-C9_iSLgKQ'})
None
```

Google app script function that I want to call:

```
function apiTest(){
  print("CALL")
  return "Hello World!"
}
```